# Login fail using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, testng

My webdriver is the last version, my code have Thread.sleep also, but I can't login to the page.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

WebDriver driver;
  @BeforeTest
    public void navegador() throws InterruptedException {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                  "C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(3000);         
    }

  @Test
  public void f() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("somewebpage");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("LOGIN")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("myemail");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("mypassword");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[2]/button")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
  @AfterTest
  public void cierre() {
      driver.quit();
  }

}
```

The webpage send me this message "These credentials do not match our records." 
But when I do it manually, the page give me access to home.

I can't pass from the login page, Suggestions?

Comment: Are you running it on local or remote driver?

Comment: What is the url of "somewebpage"? Or can you provide its html source code?

Comment: seems to me it's running as local by the ' System.setProperty '.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can give try  this check whether test works in debug mode.
If test is still not working in debug mode. then try to fetch values of both username and password field after sent by script and check whether its going correctly as manually.

Still its failing please share html code.